# How to install BIDS in a server

Tags: ssis, ssas, bids

1. Install BIDS

Hi,
anyone can help to install business intelligence development studio in a server.
Thank you

Comment: Help with which part exactly? Are you having a specific problem installing it (if so, describe the problem) or don't you know where to find an installer (in which case the question doesn't seem particularly appropriate for [so], as, if nothing more, questions must demonstrate a sufficient attempt from the asker at solving the problem his/herself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012, you can download and install the bits from MS. [VS 2012 Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36843) [Installation walkthrough for 2012](http://www.mattmasson.com/2013/04/installing-ssis-for-visual-studio-2012/)

Otherwise, you will need to find your install media and click through the SQL Server installation, either for a new instance or for update to an existing. When you get to the feature selection, you will want to select BIDS/SSDT development tools.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Could you clarify your second sentence?